# Converting linq query to lambda syntax

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to show heatmap when message sent by day and hour and I wrote some linq query.

Original SQL Query

```
SELECT weekday, hr , count(message.hour)
FROM (SELECT days.dow as weekday, hours.hour as hr from days left join hours,message on message.dow = days.dow group by days.dow, hours.hour)
LEFT JOIN message on message.dow = weekday and message.hour = hr group by weekday, hr
```

Message class

```
public class Message
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

LINQ query(it works)

```
int[] Hours = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 };
int[] Days = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
/*
  Load Message data from csv file
  ...
*/
var heatmap = from d in
                  (from message in Messages
                  join h in Hours on message.Timestamp.Hour equals h
                  join d in Days on (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek equals d
                  orderby d, h
                  group new { d, h } by new { d, h } into g
                  select new { Weekday = g.Key.d, Hour = g.Key.h })
              join message in Messages on new { d.Weekday, d.Hour } equals new { Weekday = (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek, Hour = message.Timestamp.Hour }
              group new { d.Weekday, d.Hour } by new { d.Weekday, d.Hour } into g
              select new { Weekday = g.Key.Weekday, Hour = g.Key.Hour, Total = g.Count() };
```

Sample result heatmap data

```
      Weekday    Hour    Total
[0]     0         0       120
[1]     0         1       57
[2]     0         2       79
...
[167]   6         23      89
```

and here is the code that I converted LINQ query to lambda syntax code but it doesn't work! :(

```
int[] Hours = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 };
int[] Days = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
/*
  Load Message data from csv file
  ...
*/
var heatmapLambda = (Messages.Join(Hours, message => message.Timestamp.Hour, h => h, (m, h) => new { m, h })
                                  .Join(Days, m => (int)m.m.Timestamp.DayOfWeek, d => d, (m,d) => new { m, d })
                                  .OrderBy(m => new {m.d, m.m.h})
                                  .GroupBy(g => new {g.d, g.m.h})
                                  .Select(r => new {
                                      Weekday = r.Key.d,
                                      Hour = r.Key.h
                                  }))
                              .Join(Messages, d => new {d.Weekday, d.Hour}, m => new { Weekday = (int)m.Timestamp.DayOfWeek, Hour = m.Timestamp.Hour}, (d,h) => new { d.Weekday, d.Hour})
                              .GroupBy(g => new { g.Weekday, g.Hour})
                              .Select(r => new { Weekday = r.Key.Weekday, Hour = r.Key.Hour, Count = r.Count() });
```

`heatmapLambda` has no any items. what is right lambda expression of my linq query?

Comment: Could you please explain what do u want to achieve with the query. And an example collection of Messages would be helpful too.

Comment: @MaximFleitling I added Message class implementation and result heatmap data collection

Comment: In the lambda, shouldn't there be a foreach somewhere ? Like foreach(message in messages) ?

Comment: Joins work better with linq syntax.  You can then put a parenthesis around the join and use lambda expressions.  So it should look like this : (from d ... lambda expression).GroupBy(linq expressions ...)

Comment: @jdweng thank you for reply. I have a another question, is there difference between linq query and lambda syntax?

Comment: Yes! linq has periods and lambda doesn't.

Comment: Generally, it helps to call `ToList()` on the query result in order to actually execute the query. This reveals things like exceptions that are thrown during query execution.

Comment: @Mystika - There is effectively no difference with the LINQ query and lambda syntax. Obviously they look different, but the compiler does all the magic to to the query syntax into the lambda syntax and then compiles that. So there is no semantic difference at all.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for nice answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the primary goal of a query should be to get a correct **result** in a best way, rather than the syntax used (query, method or mixed).

In your case, the query is far from optimal - unnecessary joins, grouping and ordering. From what I see, you are trying to get the count of the messages per each `(weekday, hour)` combination from the `Days` and `Hours` collections, which can be achieved by simple Cartesian product combined with [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
var query = 
    from key in (from d in Days from h in Hours select new { Weekday = d, Hour = h })
    join m in Messages
    on key equals new { Weekday = (int)m.Timstamp.DayOfWeek, m.Timestamp.Hour } into items
    select new { key.Weekday, key.Hour, Total = items.Count() };
```

In general when working with joins and or groupings, using the query syntax is easier and more natural due to transparent identifiers. In this particular case method syntax is not so different, but you need to know how to map the constructs:

```
var query = 
    Days.SelectMany(d => Hours, (d, h) => new { Weekday = d, Hour = h })
    .GroupJoin(Messages, 
        key => key, m => new { Weekday = (int)m.Timstamp.DayOfWeek, m.Timestamp.Hour },
        (key, items) => new { key.Weekday, key.Hour, Total = items.Count() });
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're doing quite a few unnecessary joins.

When you do:

```
from message in Messages
join h in Hours on message.Timestamp.Hour equals h
join d in Days on (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek equals d
```

...it is the same as:

```
    from message in Messages
    let h = message.Timestamp.Hour
    let d = (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek
```

And then when you do:

```
join message in Messages on new { d.Weekday, d.Hour } equals new { Weekday = (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek, Hour = message.Timestamp.Hour }
```

...you're basically rejoining back to your original messages.

I think that this is the equivalent query:

```
var heatmap =
    from message in Messages
    let Hour = message.Timestamp.Hour
    let Weekday = (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek
    orderby Weekday, Hour
    group message by new { Weekday, Hour } into gms
    select new { gms.Key.Weekday, gms.Key.Hour, Count = gms.Count() };
```

...so, if that's the case, then this is what you need using lambdas:

```
var heatmap =
    Messages
        .OrderBy(message => (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek)
        .ThenBy(message => message.Timestamp.Hour)
        .GroupBy(message => new { Weekday = (int)message.Timestamp.DayOfWeek, message.Timestamp.Hour })
        .Select(gms => new { gms.Key.Weekday, gms.Key.Hour, Count = gms.Count() });
```

Comment: Long story short: `OrderBy(m => new { m.d, m.m.h })` throws an exeption, that `IComparable` has to be implemented, while `OrderBy(m => m.d).ThenBy(m => m.m.h)` works because integers are comparable.

Comment: @grek40 - That's fine, but what's it got to do with my answer?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a bit misleading I guess. Basically, you gave some valuable advide how to optimize the query and somewhere along the way, you also solved the specific blocking issue of the original query. I think in terms of answering the question it would be important to highlight the minimal solution, so others can understand which parts are absolutely necessary and which parts are suggested optimizations (that are also very important in this case)